# AngularJS - set callback result to controller variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, events

I have an event, declared like this:

```
event.watch(function (error, result) {
    // result will contain various information
    // including the arguments given to the `Person`
    // call.
    if (!error) {
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

If I try to assign to a variable the result of the event, like this:

```
vm.fName = result.fName;
```

And then log the variable outside the event callback function, in console will be displayed `undefined`. If I log the variable inside the event the correct value is displayed.
From my understanding this is an asynchronous call and `console.log(vm.fName);`will be called before the event finishes and the value displayed in UI is empty because it's undefined.

I need to store the result in a variable and use bind it further to my ng-models.
I tried many workarounds but none of them seemed to work.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

**### EDIT**
Here is an example of what is happening:

```
var response = {};

setTimeout(function () {
    response = {
        "fName": "John",
        "age": 22
    };
    console.log(response);
}, 2000);

console.log(response);
```

If you run this example you will see that the final console.log will be called before the asynchronous call.
So the value returned to UI will be an empty object {}.
After the call is finished the response will look like this:

```
response = {
            "fName": "John",
            "age": 22
        };
```

But in the UI already was displayed the empty object.
I need a way to wait for the async call to finish before setting my variable.

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem as a whole. Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I edited my original question with an example.

Comment: OK, I just wanted to be sure what the problem was. You don't need to worry about when the response will "bring" the data. Just bind the variable in the UI and update the value of it inside the event (can you do that?) angularjs will update the view for you if the event is inside the angularjs context ;)

Comment: I believed so too, but if I declare vm.fName to be an empty string for example and add it inside a html element like <h2>{{vm.fName}}</h2> the value displayed in UI will be the empty string even after the event finishes. I think I'm missing something here.

Comment: The solution was to call `$scope.$apply()` inside the callback of the event forcing the UI to refresh.

Comment: Yeah, that it is what I meant with _"..if the event is inside the angularjs context.."_. It's good you solved the problem :) You  should post the answer in order to help people in future with the same problem ;)